# Why are the macros gone after a user saves the spreadsheet?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

We have spreadsheets  with macros stored on a server. These are stored as .xlsm.

A user had W7 reinstalled on his PC. Now if he accesses a spreadsheet from the server the macros are missing.  When he saved the spreadsheet back no other user could access the macro.

Does anyone have an answer why this happened?

Comment: When he saved it, does it remain as a .xlsm file? I think there is a trust center settings you may need to edit but I don't have access to a PC with Office Suite to test it

Comment: "no other user could access the macro" - what does this mean? Macros not exists in the workbook anymore, or don't work?

Comment: For the first comment, the trust centre settings were set on the users PC to 'enable all macros'.  For the second comment, the macros did no exist in the workbook anymore, they had vanished from the file on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible things going on here; 1) when the file is opened and 2) when the file is closed.

1. For security reasons, Excel disables all macros by default.  The
   user needs to modify the `Macro Security` in the Trust Center 
   (*File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings button > Macro Settings*) to be able to use and edit a macro-enabled sheet.
2. When saving, Excel will ask the user to save the sheet as
   `Macro-Enabled` with and extension of `xlsm`. If the user chooses
   not to do this, it will save the sheet as a standard sheet without
   the macros.